# How do I organize functional code in PHP (or any language)

Tags: php, functional-programming

I've been trying my hand at functional programming using PHP. I understand all the basics; closures, lambdas, referential transparency etc.

What I don't understand and can't find much information on is how to structure the whole project. How to group functions together into what kind of folder structure.

What I've been doing is using empty classes with only static functions, as this provides me with namespaces. Is this a good idea or is there a better way?

Comment: @lonut Sometimes you should get off your high horse and stop making assumptions.

Comment: Sorry if I offended, that's what worked for me. I should have been explicit about that.

Comment: @lonut It just came across of elitist. FWIW I started programming in the 80's on my spectrum 48k+ and have learned over 20 languages along the way. I know some would consider it perverse, but I like experimenting with PHP; I've *had* to use it so much that I am very familiar with it's problems so I find it easy and fast to experiment in.

Comment: @SystemicPlural I see. Then you've got at least three times more experience than I do. And, I've got nothing against PHP, I've been using it for 4-5 years, it's just that as soon as I played with Scheme and Haskell I could come up with ideas, feasible in PHP or JavaScript, that I couldn't see before. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: @cuewizchris At least its not llamas. Cheers.

Comment: Namespaces are natively supported in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php. The folder structure can replicate the namespace structure you use in the code. Don't "abuse" classes as namespaces (even if you use an older PHP version, using classes as function containers just feels wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Just define the functions you need in either namespaces or as static class members.

If you look at how functional languages (as in languages in which functional programming was intended), then basic namespaces is all you need to group functions into libraries. In PHP you can put functions directly into namespaces, or you can put them in static methods inside classes if you prefer the `::` separator over `\`.

In many functional languages you end up using a lot of auxiliary functions that are only intended for a local scope.  This situation can be handled as you would otherwise handle private methods in PHP (either by prefixing underscores or by using the `private` keyword).

For other languages than PHP you will find similar reasoning: Use whatever method of grouping functions together (modules, namespaces, classes, structures, etc.). There are no arguments from a functional programming perspective that should change this.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to know.